# firstOrCreate returns Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a database seeder where I want to seed a `Topic` table. These are saved per `Organization`. The name of the `Topic` is a `key`. For each `Organization` there are multiple `Topics`, and sometimes an `array` with the same names could be inserted. To avoid this error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

I am using the `firstOrCreate` option from `Eloquent`. It looks for the `organization_id` and the `name`. If they don't exist together yet, it should insert a record, else it should skip inserting the record.

```
public function run($organizationId, $topicName)
    {
        $this->disableForeignKeys();

        $topic = Topic::allTenants()
            ->firstOrCreate([
                'organization_id' => $organizationId,
                'name' => $topicName,
            ], [
                'description' => 'Not used',
            ]);

        $this->enableForeignKeys();

        return $topic->id;
    }
```

But when I insert a `Topic`, with an unused `organization_id` it gives me the error that the record already exist. But that isn't the case because the `organization_id` and `name` don't exist in the database yet. So why does it give me this error? It looks like it isn't even checking for both `organization_id` and `name`.

These are the Schemas for the Topics table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class TopicsUniqueFields extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('topics', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unique(['organisation_id', 'name']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('topics', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropUnique(['organisation_id', 'name']);
        });
    }
}
```

The one above sets the unique fields for the Topics table.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateTopicsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('topics', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('organisation_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('organisation_id')
                ->references('id')->on('organisations');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('topics');
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the name field has a unique constraint. So if `org1+name1` exist and `org1+name1` don't exist, BUT `org2+name1` and you try to insert `org1+name1` into a database where the name field must be unique then you'll get a duplicate entry error, because `name1` already exists. Show the schemas for the relevant tables.

Comment: I've updated my question @GerardRoche

Comment: Does changing `$topic = Topic::allTenants()->firstOrCreate([` to `$topic = Topic::firstOrCreate([` work, If yes, then the `allTenants()` method is obviouly not doing what you think it should be doing. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Comment: That didn't work @GerardRoche. That function makes sure some package doesn't add unnecessary IDs in the query.

Comment: Try looking at your mysql log for more information. On linux it'll most likely be in `/var/log/mysql/*`. The error message should be giving you more details e.g. `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1922-1' for key 'IDX_STOCK_PRODUCT'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is definitely the `organization_id` or `name` fields that are duplicated, do you have any other unique fields on your table?

The only other think I could think of is `Topic::allTenants()` method limiting the scope of the query? i.e. Topics exist with the `organization_id` or `name` field that are out of scope of the query.

Comment: I don't think `allTenants()` is the problem because the only thing it does is making sure that there is no extra `organization_id` added to the `query`. The `allTenants` is a `function` from a `package` we're using here. The error occurs on the `name` value.

Comment: It was indeed the package that caused the query to not do what I expected. I fixed it by adding this line of code: `Landlord::addTenant('organization_id', $organizationId);`